# How do I specify a range of unicode characters in a regular-expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to match a range of Unicode characters and I am wondering how to do it. I can match simple ranges like [a-zA-Z] but how do I specify a range of Unicode characters. I've tried

```
[#xD8-#xF6]
```

without any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try:

```
[\u00D8-\u00F6]
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Python 2.X

```
u'[\u00d8-\u00f6]'
```

#### Python 3.X

```
'[\u00d8-\u00f6]'
```

Comment: Matching unicode characters with grep: grep -Pe '[\x{1200}-\x{137c}]'