# Wordpress: Changing only the color of Chinese characters in page title & menu

Tags: css, wordpress

Transitioning from application development to web development here so I am still trying to figure everything out.

How do you change only the color of Chinese characters in the page title and menu from Wordpress? It should be done in the css, but I wasn't sure how to detect Chinese characters that way. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is not a programming language and therefore does not have the ability to detect Chinese character—this has to be done by using regex to filter individual characters on your page by their Unicode character range, and pick out those that fall within the CJKUI block. This range is [very well discussed in another SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode). To summarise the range:

- CJK Unified Ideographs: `\u4E00` to `\u9FFF`
- CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A: `\u3400` to `\u4DFF`
- CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B: `\u20000` to `\u2A6DF`
- CJK Compatibility Ideographs: `\uF900` to `\uFAFF`
- CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement: `\u2F800` to `\u2FA1F`

The first range would usually suffice, but if you are working with Chinese texts containing rare, dated characters then expanding your selection to include the full CJKUI range is favourable.

However, by using regex on a large amount of text you are performing an *expensive* matching operation—still feasible for small snippets for texts where you know for sure Chinese characters will turn up. The trick is to [detect the Unicode range (it is asked in the Python tag but also works for JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748855/how-do-i-specify-a-range-of-unicode-characters-in-a-regular-expression-in-python) of each character iteratively, and wrap it within a `<span lang="zh">` element (using the `lang` attribute is semantically valid and recommended) with a specific class so that you can style it anyway you desire using CSS.

For the regex pattern, the trick is to use the character range selector: `[...-...]` (read more [here](http://regexone.com/lesson/character_ranges)). For the most reduced CJKUI set, you can use `[\u4E00-\u9FFF]`. However, as mentioned before if you want to really match to **all possible Chinese unicode characters**, you will have to use the full set: `[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\u20000-\u2A6DF\uF900-\uFAFF\u2F800-\u2FA1F]`

```js
$(function() {
  $('h1, p').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(text.replace(/([\u4E00-\u9FFF])/g, '<span lang="zh">$1</span>'));
  });
});
```

```css
span[lang="zh"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Title 馦騜 here</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum 跣鉌 dolor sit 嬞 amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 蔍 Aliquam dignissim justo metus, nec rhoncus diam 娀 mollis sed. Pellentesque eu 庣 neque sit amet sapien accumsan accumsan 餳 vel nec quam. Sed rutrum 嬚 id justo quis pretium. Vestibulum 鍹 eu ligula id magna vehicula rhoncus nec a tortor. Integer id 楋dolor vitae mi gravida euismod ac eget 馻 dui. Pellentesque eu enim at erat 嬔 pellentesque posuere. Duis ligula magna, pretium sed 騧 sagittis eu, mollis a nibh. Integer ultrices 噈 molestie scelerisque. Maecenas 羭聧蔩 eget nulla sodales, pulvinar magna non, 嫶 vestibulum odio. Sed a luctus mi. In nec 烒 cursus justo. Nunc lacinia 烢 massa a eros semper scelerisque. Fusce dictum lacus 珛 nec ipsum 駷pellentesque, id finibus sapien lacinia.</p>
```

The best solution though, is to pre-process your HTML/user input with regex once, which will do the same as above, so that runtime regex wrapping of Chinese character can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks Terry! I modified the code so that only header titles are affected, hope you don't mind!

Comment: In terms of the Wordpress framework, where should the code snippet be located in? I couldn't get it to parse in extras.php

Comment: You should save the JS in a file (putting it anywhere is ok, but saving it to the themes JS folder would be a nice way to keep things organized) and load it using `wp_enqueue_script`, and making sure that you list jquery as a dependency: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: In which php file should I load the script?

Comment: It should ideally be in `functions.php`, although it can technically be in any PHP file loaded by your theme. Also note that jQuery that comes bundled with Wordpress is on compatibility mode, which means the jQuery object is not mapped to the `$` alias. More details in the link I've mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes I checked that link out already, thank you Terry you've been incredibly helpful!

Comment: I wrapped the JS using jQuery(document).ready(function($) { });, added wp_enqueue_style( 'red-zh-char-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/red-zh-char.js', array( 'jquery') ); to function harmonic_scripts() in functions.php and added the css code to a new stylesheet lang.css in themes/css folder but it doesn't seem to be working - any idea as to why that is the case?

Comment: Check your console log to see if the script is throwing any error. Check your network tab if the JS file is loaded correctly. Check if the path is pointing to the right file. There are many things that could go wrong, but that's already beyond the scope of your original question.