# regular expression and bytes

Tags: python, regex, split, byte, python-re

I have a big string of bytes. I need to split it by some preamble.
The preamble contains four bytes. The first, second and fourth bytes are fixed, and the third byte is changeable. I want to split it using  a regular expression in Python.

For example, I have preamble: `\xde\x00\x12\x74` and byte string.

```py
string = b'\xde\x00\x12\x74hbcoawnxasnokcasnlawnmclkasmlfmapodmaw\xde\x00\x66\x74dawnioxhawondajncoianoineaopcmaopscamp\xde\x00\x98\x74dawxaskaodjopawnxkpancokaenjocnaocnawo'
string_split = re.split(rb'\xde\x00\x\d{2}\x74', string)
```

I cannot understand how to make a pattern for finding the preamble.

I tried some pattern, internet searching.

Comment: `\x12` is a byte, you can't use `\d{2}` here instead of `12` as it is just matching digits, not that byte. So, what does the preamble consist of? What bytes can there be? List them.

Comment: The first, second and fourth bytes are fixed, and the third byte is changeable. Third byte can be anyone.

Comment: Third byte is  any valid byte

Comment: Aha, so use `.`- `rb'\xde\x00.\x74'` - https://ideone.com/Fjvnes

Comment: thanks. It worked. By what if i want to use a pattern for byte, for example, from A0 to AF. How can i discribe this? "\xA."???

Comment: Easy as pie - `[\xA0-\xAF]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748855/how-do-i-specify-a-range-of-unicode-characters-in-a-regular-expression-in-python

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: If your preamble is binary and in bytes, `\xde\x00\x12\x74` where the first second and fourth bytes are fixed and the third is variable.
Since the third is unknown, that range must be `0x00-0xFF` The regex then becomes `\xde\x00[\x00-\xff]\x74` where the class matches a single character that can be any character in the byte range.